# Why Bezier Interplation of Blender is not as much dramatic and cinematic as of other softwares?

Tags: interpolation

I am working on a project and when i use bezier interpolation, it looks like linear interpolation in real time with no dramatic or cinematic effects at all on the objects. is there some settings which am i missing or is there any solution for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115168/discussion-on-question-by-zain-ul-abedin-why-bezier-interplation-of-blender-is-n).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "cinematic", but I will assume you want the animation speed to make more dynamic.

Go to the graph editor, and select all of the control points. At the top, switch the pivot to individual centers and scale all the control points up. This makes the curve much more dynamic wherever there are control points.